# Django ManyToManyField through relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

So, here is the thing.
The app is supposed to work with only one database so every data is stored in the same place.
My problem lies on how to make the following relationship work:
Users should participate in several Process, and a Process should have several Users and on each Process they (Users) must have a specific Role.
So, sometimes a User object can participate on Process A with role X and on Process B with Role Y
So I wrote this code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Process(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    party = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Role',
        through_fields=('process', 'user'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Role(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    process = models.ForeignKey(Process)
    X = 'X'
    Y = 'Y'
    Z = 'Y'       
    ROLE_CHOICE = (
        (X, X),
        (Y, Y),
        (Z, Z),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROLE_CHOICE,
        default=X)
```

The problem is, Roles should be limit to 3 options only, but as I create new instances through Role, Role objects (X, Y and Z) keep being created even though they already exist.
Is there another way of doing all this relationship works?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you give an example of what you're trying to do? What do you mean by "how could I relate it to a user"?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I edited the text, take a look. And just as an example: A User logs in, he needs to see all the Process he/she is involved with, and, inside the Process, his/her Role in this specific Process. Get it?

Comment: I get it, but what's the actual problem you're facing? "It doesn't work how it should" is not a good description. For what it's worth, what you're describing is a very typical use case for M2M with `through`, and I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry there is my question, I think now I manage to make myself clear.